# Словить AccessDeniedException в SpringSecurity REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

Как словить `AccessDeniedException` при запросе к REST API?

**Есть такой конфиг:**

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/owner/register").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new ApiAccessDeniedHandler());
```

Но этот `ApiAccessDeniedHandler` не срабатывает. Что не так?

`.antMatchers("/api/v1/owner/register").anonymous()` - так я сделал ибо аннотации `@Secured` и `@PreAuthorize` не работают, хотя `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` настроен на то и на то:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
```

Comment: Что если разделить всё на несколько выражений? Типа `http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/owner/register").anonymous();

http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new ApiAccessDeniedHandler());`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб изначально сделал у себя только второй вариант и все равно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы неправильно конфигурируете [AccessDeniedHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html). Добавьте следующую конфигурацию

```
@Bean
public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
    return new ApiAccessDeniedHandler();
}

//...
.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
```