# Словить AccessDeniedException в SpringSecurity REST API 2.0

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt

Данный вопрос уже задавался [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870257/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-accessdeniedexception-%D0%B2-springsecurity-rest-api)

Но к сожалению данный вопрос не закрыт и ответ который там предложен не работает.

У меня есть класс унаследованный от WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter который имеет:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                //.antMatchers("/auth/login", "/auth/registration", "/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("USER")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(personDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler(){
        return new ApiAccessDeniedHandler();
    }
```

Также есть класс:

```
public class ApiAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, AccessDeniedException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }
}
```

Однако все равно в метод handle так и не заходит при появлении ошибки AccessDeniedException.

подключенный фильтр отрабатывает вроде правильно, вот его код:

```
@Component
public class JWTFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JWTUtil jwtUtil;
    private final PersonDetailsService personDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public JWTFilter(JWTUtil jwtUtil, PersonDetailsService personDetailsService) {
        this.jwtUtil = jwtUtil;
        this.personDetailsService = personDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String authHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authHeader != null && !authHeader.isBlank() && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String jwt = authHeader.substring(7);

            if (jwt.isBlank()) {
                httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST,
                        "Invalid JWT Token in Bearer Header");
            } else {
                try {
                    String username = jwtUtil.validateTokenAndRetrieveClaim(jwt);
                    UserDetails userDetails = personDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                    userDetails,
                                    userDetails.getPassword(),
                                    userDetails.getAuthorities());

                    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                    }
                } catch (JWTVerificationException | UsernameNotFoundException e) {
                    httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST,
                            "Invalid JWT Token");
                }
            }
        } else {
            httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST,
                    "Invalid authorization");
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

Перерыл уже море вариантов и никакой не сработал, думаю, что упускаю какую-то мелочь как всегда.